# Bloomberg-alternatives for intraday stock price data?

Tags: historical-data, bloomberg, intraday

Given the limitation Bloomberg imposes in terms of the number of days you can go into the past when retrieving historical intraday data, what are similarly reliable alternative solutions? I require some data for a one-time research project, so I would ideally want to download or purchase the data just once, without a subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete intraday data history can be obtained through the Thomson Reuters DataScope Tick History (TRDTH) archive: http://thomsonreuters.com/tick-history

You may ask them for a trial subscription.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tickdata.com/

They provide trade and quote and there is also an API.

Answer (score 1):

You may try HQD software, downloads 1-min interval data from Yahoo or Google Finance http://www.ashkon.com/downloader.html

Answer (score 1):

[Quandl](https://quandl.com) has some good intraday datasets but requires a subscription

[FirstRateData](http://firstratedata.com) has some free datasets for SP500 and major FX, indices.

Answer (score 1):

https://algoseek.com/ is an option if you are looking for historical intraday stock data in the US market. You can easily download their samples and the dataset you need on their Explore Data page.

Answer (score 0):

[Money.net](https://www.money.net) provide a relative to Bloomberg Terminal solution.

The platform is a web-application, so you don't need to download the desktop client itself. You could also download tick-data in trial 14 period. But I am not sure about limitations. Their product is subscription based, and it's commercial, but I guess they could extend your trial period for academic purposes.

Also, if you are looking for a data for a back-testing your strategy, you should take a look for a playground /sandbox exchange services, like [Helix](https://github.com/penberg/helix) for NYSE and so on.